# Detecting program's name Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am working on a project and one part of it is to have the program tell what it's own name is. I am later going to compile the PY file into an EXE, which I will rename. Is there any way for the program to tell what it's called?

Comment: Sounds like `sys.argv[0]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sys.argv[0]` is the path it was invoked with. For output, you usually want to wrap that in `os.path.basename` to avoid including the full path, sticking to just the name of the executable itself, e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, sys

print(os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]))
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! Turned out to be a lot easier than I thought it would.

Answer (score 1):

The Python sys module provides access to any command-line arguments via the sys.argv. This serves two purposes −

```
sys.argv is the list of command-line arguments.

len(sys.argv) is the number of command-line arguments.
```

Here sys.argv[0] is the program ie. script name.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm